# Fonts hosed after following ubuntu wiki directions

Tags: fonts

I'm on 14.10 with classic gnome. I went to [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts) Ubuntu Wiki page and followed the directions enabling bitmapped fonts:

...

```
cd /etc/fonts/conf.d/
sudo rm /etc/fonts/conf.d/10* && sudo rm -rf 70-no-bitmaps.conf && sudo ln -s ../conf.avail/70-yes-bitmaps.conf .
sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig
```

But now my browser and app fonts are all something ugly and jaggy. All I wanted to do was enable bitmapped terminus for my terminal... How can I get my original state back?

Comment: **Never** enter something in a terminal window that you don't understand.

Comment: I guess I'll go to another Ubuntu machine and copy this directory. That's all I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by simply grabbing the whole /etc/fonts directory off another U14.10 computer, wiping out the bad stuff on this computer, copying over the new /etc/fonts/, then running

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig
```

. . . logged out, logged back in. Solved. All I wanted to do was use bitmapped terminus in my terminal. . .